# New machine: 256GB PCIe for OS + 2TB SATA SSD for home, or 2TB PCIe for OS+home together

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd, pcie

I'm setting up a new desktop (i7 10700) that originally came with a 256GB PCIe disk and 3 SATA ports.

Not sure if it's better to install the Ubuntu OS on that disk, and add another disk for my home directory (2TB SATA SSD), or if I should replace the PCIe disk with a 2TB one, and put all together.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I would definitely recommend having your OS installed to an SSD to take advantage of dramatically faster random read speeds compared to an HDD.  Beyond that, how much space you need and how you organize it is entirely up to you and your use case

Comment: @Henry It all really depends on how you want to do it. I would take advantage of the multiple disks personally. For example, in my current rig I've got a 1TB M.2 and a 2TB SATA, and I've joined the storage into one large pool (sans /boot and /boot/efi) so I can have almost 3TB combined between the two. I can post how I did that as an answer if you'd like. Otherwise, I would use the smaller disk for the system and the larger disk for your home directory